# filepicker.io policy not working

Tags: filepicker.io, filepicker

I have the following PHP generated.

```
$policy = base64_encode(json_encode(array("maxsize"=>1, 'path'=>'tmp/', 'expiry'=>strtotime("+5 minutes"), 'extension'=>'.pdf', 'call'=>array('pick','store'))));
$sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $policy, FILEPICKER_SECRET);
```

It is correct because when I turned on security, it did not complain wrong signature. The filepicker codes as below.

```
filepicker.pick(
                {policy: policy, signature:signature},
                function(fpfiles) {
                    console.log(fpfiles);
                }
            );
```

Now nothing seems to work.
1) all types of files can be uploaded
2) uploaded files does not resides in 'tmp' folder in s3
3) all file size can be uploaded

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The filepicker.io policies do not set the behavior of the dialog, only validate it. If you want to control the file extension and path you should specify those parameters in the filepicker.pick() call. See https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/security/ for more details.